# ¿Cómo hacer un gráfico y sub gráficos de pie en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Cómo podría en R hacer este tipo de gráficos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que paquete se tendría que usar o incluso, se puede hacer con `ggplot2`?

Aquí dejo los datos.

```
    V1
A   894
B   
B1  138
B2  4414
```

O en su defecto, alguna alternativa gráfica que pueda representar lo mismo que este gráfico de pie?

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo gráficos de torta tiene una muy mala prensa en el mundillo de la estadística, si bien en el área de negocios y en la presentaciones son moneda corriente. El principal defecto es que visualmente no es tan claro la diferencias entre las áreas, en ese sentido un gráfico de barras tradicional, incluso mejor, de áreas superpuestas es mucho más claro. Por algo en `ggplot` no existe un `geom_pie()` oficial.

Justamente, se puede "simular" esta gráfica, partiendo de un `geom_bar()` y modificando el sistema de coordenadas mediante `coord_polar()`. Pero en tu caso, tienes una dificultad adicional que el gráfico es de dos niveles. Por lo que en primer lugar, vamos a preparar los datos:

```
library("tidyverse")
data <- data.frame(V1 = c('A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2'),
                   valor = c(894, 138 + 4414, 138, 4414)
)               

data %>% 
  mutate(grupo = ifelse(nchar(V1)==1, '', gsub("\\d","", V1))) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>%
  mutate(prop = valor / sum(valor) *100) %>%
  arrange(grupo, desc(prop)) %>% 
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop ) -> plot_data

plot_data


# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   grupo [2]
  V1    valor grupo  prop  ypos
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B      4552 ""    83.6   41.8
2 A       894 ""    16.4   91.8
3 B2     4414 "B"   97.0   48.5
4 B1      138 "B"    3.03  98.5
```

Aquí lo que construimos es unos datos amigables para `ggplot`, hemos construído dos grupos, para el principal y el detalle de "B", hemos calculado la proporción de cada barra en porcentaje y un `ypos` para posicionar la etiqueta, finalmente:

```
plot_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x="", y=prop, fill=V1)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(V1,":\n", valor)), color = "white", size=4) +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
    facet_wrap(~grupo) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Hay dos temas importantes a señalar, `coord_polar("y", start=0)` para definir las coordenadas polares y `facet_wrap(~grupo)` para facetar por grupo y así generar las dos tortas. El resto es "azucar" estético.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es interesante comparar como se vería la gráfica, en la forma tradicional de barras, simplemente hay que comenta `coord_polar("y", start=0)`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Su respuesta fue de gran ayuda. 

Entiendo que los pies no reflejen bien las diferencias entre áreas. Pero por diversidad debería de haber una función que las realice de una manera más estética que lo hecho con R base. 

Me entristece que no haya una función para este tipo de gráficos. Pero ni modo.